# How to display user name and surname in main page after Django login

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Instead of the user, I want to display the user name and surname in the main page, after the log in. But my user model is extended by another form which holds the name and surname fields.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

This will display the user name. But my second form has a OnetoOneField with the User model. I tried something like user.form2.name but it's not a solution.

Comment: share your models

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UNGjz2N5 Here are my views:in case is student or in case is teacher, I need to show surname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ request.user.<name_of_one_to_one_model_in_lower_case>.surname }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Not really working... Here are my views: https://pastebin.com/UNGjz2N5 in case is student or in case is teacher, I need to show surname

Comment: please add the models

Comment: user.student.surname should work for a student, and user.teacher.surname for a teacher